# How many resources like shared_memory ROSCPP used?

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to ask this question because of I found that if I don't care about resources,sometimes it will run into strange producure.

For example, when some code A run successfully.

I change to A' and failed.

So I change back to A but also failed.

Therefore, I think it maybe caused by system resources.

So my question is:

When I rebuild ROSCPP and want to run it, which resource I should remove first by tools similar to ipcs?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12634/how-many-resources-like-shared_memory-roscpp-used?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you change things you only need to recompile.  Make sure that you have recompiled all your libraries and their dependencies which connect to the changes you made.  In general a rosmake will cover everything.  There are a few packages, usually 3rd party packages that download external sources, where a make clean is necessary.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-03-16**:
So what you mean is roscpp doesn't use any system resources like shared memory? Thank you~